# How to properly collect an array of lines in zsh

Tags: shell-script, zsh

I thought the following would group the output of `my_command` in an array of lines:

```
IFS='\n' array_of_lines=$(my_command);
```

so that `$array_of_lines[1]` would refer to the first line in the output of `my_command`, `$array_of_lines[2]` to the second, and so forth.

However, the command above doesn't seem to work well. It seems to also split the output of `my_command` around the character `n`, as I have checked with `print -l $array_of_lines`, which I believe prints elements of an array line by line. I have also checked this with:

```
echo $array_of_lines[1]
echo $array_of_lines[2]
...
```

In a second attempt, I thought adding `eval` could help:

```
IFS='\n' array_of_lines=$(eval my_command);
```

but I got the exact same result as without it.

Finally, following the answer on [List elements with spaces in zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28854/list-elements-with-spaces-in-zsh), I have also tried using parameter expansion flags instead of `IFS` to tell zsh how to split the input and collect the elements into an array, i.e.:

```
array_of_lines=("${(@f)$(my_command)}");
```

But I still got the same result (splitting happening on `n`)

With this, I have the following questions:

**Q1.** What are **"the proper"** ways of collecting the output of a command in an array of lines?

**Q2.** How can I specify `IFS` to split on newlines only?

**Q3.** If I use parameter expansion flags as in my third attempt above (i.e. using `@f`) to specify the splitting, does zsh ignore the value of `IFS`? Why didn't it work above?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

TL, DR:

```
array_of_lines=("${(@f)$(my_command)}")
```

---

First mistake (→ Q2): `IFS='\n'` sets `IFS` to the two characters `\` and `n`. To set `IFS` to a newline, use `IFS=$'\n'`.

Second mistake: to set a variable to an array value, you need parentheses around the elements: `array_of_lines=(foo bar)`.

This would work, except that it strips empty lines, because consecutive whitespace counts as a single separator:

```
IFS=$'\n' array_of_lines=($(my_command))
```

You can retain the empty lines except at the very end by doubling the whitespace character in `IFS`:

```
IFS=$'\n\n' array_of_lines=($(my_command))
```

To keep trailing empty lines as well, you'd have to add something to the command's output, because this happens in the command substitution itself, not from parsing it.

```
IFS=$'\n\n' array_of_lines=($(my_command; echo .)); unset 'array_of_lines[-1]'
```

(assuming the output of `my_command` doesn't end in a non-delimited line; also note that you lose the exit status of `my_command`)

Note that all the snippets above leave `IFS` with its non-default value, so they may mess up subsequent code. To keep the setting of `IFS` local, put the whole thing into a function where you declare `IFS` local (here also taking care of preserving the command's exit status):

```
collect_lines() {
  local IFS=$'\n\n' ret
  array_of_lines=($("$@"; ret=$?; echo .; exit $ret))
  ret=$?
  unset 'array_of_lines[-1]'
  return $ret
}
collect_lines my_command
```

But I recommend not to mess with `IFS`; instead, use the `f` expansion flag to split on newlines (→ Q1):

```
array_of_lines=("${(@f)$(my_command)}")
```

Or to preserve trailing empty lines:

```
array_of_lines=("${(@f)$(my_command; echo .)}")
unset 'array_of_lines[-1]'
```

The value of `IFS` doesn't matter there. I suspect that you used a command that splits on `IFS` to print `$array_of_lines` in your tests (→ Q3).

Comment: This is so complicated! `"${(@f)...}"` is the same as `${(f)"..."}`, but in a different way. `(@)` inside double quotes means “yield one word per array element” and `(f)` means “split into an array by newline”. PS: Please link to [the docs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags)

Comment: @flyingsheep, no `${(f)"..."}` would skip empty lines, `"${(@f)...}"` preserves them. That's the same distinction between `$argv` and `"$argv[@]"`. That `"$@"` thing to preserve all elements of an array comes from the Bourne shell in the late 70s.

Comment: "You can retain the empty lines except at the very end by doubling the whitespace character in IFS:" I wouldn't expect that to work, since IFS is itself a set of characters, not a string. Is that a special case? I couldn't get it to work in my testing; double newlines in IFS still split on every line.

Comment: @MarkReed That's a zsh thing: in [IFS](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-IFS), “If an IFS white space character appears twice consecutively in the IFS, this character is treated as if it were not an IFS white space character”. With `IFS=$'\n'`, separators are sequences of newlines, so information about empty lines (consecutive newlines) disappears and the array only has the non-empty lines. With `IFS=$'\n'`, splitting happens at each newline, so there is a separate array element for each line, empty or not, apart from trailing empty lines which `$(…)` removes.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the mechanism and thought you were somehow splitting on double-newlines. Got it now, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Two issues: first, apparently double quotes also don't interpret backslash escapes (sorry about that :). Use `$'...'` quotes. And according to `man zshparam`, to collect words in an array you need to enclose them in parenthesis. So this works:

```
% touch 'a b' c d 'e f'
% IFS=$'\n' arr=($(ls)); print -l $arr
a b
c
d
e f
% print $arr[1]
a b
```

I can't answer your Q3. I hope I'll never have to know such esoteric things :).

Answer (score -3):

You can also use tr to replace newline with space:

```
lines=($(mycommand | tr '\n' ' '))
select line in ("${lines[@]}"); do
  echo "$line"
  break
done
```

Comment: what if the lines contain spaces ?

Comment: That makes no sense. Both SPC and NL are in the default value of `$IFS`. Translating one to the other makes no difference.

Comment: Were my edits reasonable? I couldn't get it to work as it was,

Comment: (timed out)  I admit I edited it without really understanding what the intent was, but I think the translation is a good start for separation based on string manipulation. I wouldn't translate to spaces, and split on them, unless the expected behavior were more like `echo`, where inputs are all more or less heaps of words separated by who cares.