# Format a help section to have the decription of the flag in one column

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, text-formatting

I have create a help section that have the following display

```
-m         This is a very very very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very very very long sentence
```

I would like to have

```
-m         This is a very very very very very very very very very very
           very very very very very very very very very very long 
           sentence.
```

Specify that I want to have 2 columns?

Comment: do you want to edit the (shell script?) to change how it's wrapping, or post-process the output afterwards?

Comment: Change how it's wrapping. What is the most used syntax  for flag description in help sections (`cmd --help`)?

Comment: Are you looking to enforce the wrapping at a fixed width (~60 chars), or dynamically based on the terminal width?

Comment: What stays constant is the distance between the flag and the description column. It may depend on the terminal width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function I put together that you could use to print help-related items, one at a time. I used the example of `-m` and the long help string from the question. The function hard-codes a width of 10 for the first column, then computes the remaining space for column 2.

```
#!/bin/bash

function printhelp() (
  c1width=10
  cols=$(tput cols)
  c2width=$((cols - c1width - 1))
  readarray -t lines < <(printf '%s' "$2" | fmt -w $c2width)
  for((line=0; line < ${#lines[*]}; line++))
  do
    if [ $line -eq 0 ]
    then
      col1="$1"
    else
      col1=" "
    fi
    printf "%-${c1width}s %-${c2width}s\n" "$col1" "${lines[line]}"
  done
)

optf='-m'
optd='This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long sentence'
printhelp "$optf" "$optd"
```

Sample output on a 50-column screen:

```
-m         This is a very very very very very
           very very very very very very very
           very very very very very very very
           very long sentence
```

and on an 80-column screen:

```
-m         This is a very very very very very very very very very very very
           very very very very very very very very very long sentence
```

and on a 130-column screen:

```
-m         This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very
           long sentence
```

and on a 150-column screen:

```
-m         This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long sentence
```

Comment: I'm not a zsh user but I've heard good things about it from smart people on here, so I'd be really surprised if it can't make an array from multi-line output.

Comment: How can I rewrite the script without using `readarray` for `zsh` users to be able to run the function.

Comment: take a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29748/117549

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you required, but an easy workaround if you do not have the parameter name and the description in the same line. With `fmt` the indentation of the second line is kept:

```bsh
$ FOO="-m\n\tThis is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long sentence"

$ echo -e $FOO
-m
    This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long sentence

$ echo -e $FOO | fmt 
-m
    This is a very very very very very very very very very very very
    very very very very very very very very very long sentence
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is also valid for `zsh`

```
FLAG="-m VARIABLE"
DESCRIPTION="This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long sentence"
DISTANCE_FLAG=3

WIDTH1=$(echo "$FLAG" | wc -c ) 
WIDTH2=$(($(tput cols)-$DISTANCE_FLAG -$WIDTH1 ))

paste <(echo $FLAG ) <(echo $DESCRIPTION | fold -sw $(( $(tput cols) -     $DISTANCE_FLAG -$WIDTH1     )) )| pr -t -e$(($DISTANCE_FLAG+$WIDTH1))
```