# double-quoting parameter (representing filename) doesn't help if spaces are contained

Tags: bash, find, quoting

When iterating over some filenames double-quoting the parameter does not prevent the filename from being broken:

```
$ mkdir temp
$ cd temp/
$ touch a\ b
$ for f in $(find .) ; do echo "$f" ; done
.
./a
b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directive `for f in $(find .)` splits the list of elements to iterate by space. In a modern shell, like zsh, [expansion flags](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28854/list-elements-with-spaces-in-zsh) could be used.

```
for f in "${(@f)$(find .)}" ; do echo "$f" ; done
```

Staying with `bash`, we can work around this [like mentioned in another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39473/command-substitution-splitting-on-newline-but-not-space) modifying the input separator, the character used to split elements, temporarily while assigning the results of `find` to a variable. Disabling gobbing for the time beeing prevents the expansion of wildcard characters, such as `*` in them.

```
set -f  # Disable globbing.
IFS=$(echo -e '\0') files=( $(find .  -print0) )  # Read newline separated files into an array.
for f in ${files[@]}; do echo $f; done
set +f  # Reenable globbing.
```

But this just shifts the problem, now it will not work when the newline is in any filename. There is just one thing forbidden in probably all filesystems which is the null character. But variables in bash may not hold this, so we cannot assign it to `IFS`.

Alternatively, xargs can be used to pass the paths  from `find` to another program. Using the `-print0` command to `find` and the `-0` switch to `xargs`, they use the null character as a separator. Adding `-n1` to the `xargs` call handles one filename at a time.

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 echo
```

Comment: `IFS='\n'` in `bash`? Are you sure that does what you want?

Comment: IFS should indeed not be tinkered with too much. Here, it is just used carefully for that one line only to convert the result to a clean array.

Comment: Tried it? There you set `IFS` to two characters: “\” and “n”. So whatever `find` outputs will be split on any of those two characters. http://pastebin.com/kj8PsrKw

Comment: I forgot an expansion character. With `$'\n'` it indeed evaluates to the newline character. http://pastebin.com/3NGSB1n4

Comment: `for f in "$(find .)"`, in any shell, runs the loop body exactly once. In your bash solution, you missed disabling globbing, and you should note that this breaks with file names containing newlines.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Personally, I would just use zsh globbing to find, but to stick with bash, I made another attempt using xargs.

Answer (score 1):

You double-quoted the variable substitution in the argument to `echo`, but not the command substitution in the iteration list of the `for` loop. That's where the split on whitespace and other nastiness is happening.

There is no fully reliable way to parse the output of `find`, because you can't tell whether a newline is part of a file name or a separator.

If you can assume that your file names don't contain newlines, then you can arrange to split the output of `find` by restricting the field separator characters to only the newline character (to protect spaces and tabs) and turning off globbing (to protect `\[?*`).

```
IFS='
'; set +f
for f in $(find .); do
  unset IFS; set +f
  echo "$f"
done
unset IFS; set +f
```

There are better ways to do this, though. The easiest way to use `find` reliably is to make it execute the command, instead of parsing its output. This is also potentially faster since the files have a good chance of being processed while their metadata is still in cache.

```
find . -exec echo {} \;
```

If you need a shell command, invoke a shell explicitly. Beware of quoting — pass the file name as an argument to the shell, don't try to interpolate it in the shell command.

```
find . -exec sh -c 'echo "$0"' {} \;
```

Instead of invoking one shell instance per file, you can group shell invocations and loop over a bunch of files. The `find` command does the bunching and ensures not to go over the command line length limit. Don't forget to pass a dummy argument as `$0` so that the files are `$1` and so on.

```
find . -exec sh -c 'for x; do echo "$x"; done' _ {} +
```

If you're using ksh93, bash or zsh, you can use their recursive globbing facility: `**/PATTERN` searches for a wildcard pattern in a directory and its subdirectories recursively. In ksh93, you need to run `set -o globstar` first. In bash, you need to run `shopt -s globstar` first, and beware that `**` also recurses inside symbolic links to directories.

```
for f in **/*; do
  echo "$f"
done
```

Zsh also has [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) that subsume most uses of `find`. Other shells have no such thing.